# NGINX Server block when MediaWiki in subdirectory

Tags: nginx, mediawiki

MediaWiki installation was in domain.com/subdirectory and worked with Apache as the server.

Pages were found domain.com/subdirectory/index.php/Main_Page

The server was changed to NGINX the other night. WordPress and XenForo work fine but the location block for MediaWiki isn't working properly.

Since I'm new to NGINX and the configuration file inner workings, I'm not sure how to write the location block to get the results equal to the Apache page layout (index.php shows).

This is my latest attempt (failed, of course).

```
 #MEDIAWIKI
 location /subdirectory/ {
     try_files $uri $uri /index.php?query_string;
 }
```

This writes to domain.com/subdirectory/title and the index.php is missing.

The documents show writing to a subdomain and this is not what I'm wanting. The index.php also needs to remain.

Thank you for providing as much information so this is solved. For example, I'm not sure if LocalSettings needs modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
index  index.php index.html;
```

Updated*

```
 location /subdirectory/ {
     index  index.php index.html;
 }
```

Using Rewrite

```
rewrite ^ /index.php?$request_uri;
```

this will forward requests to `/subdirectory/index.php?`

In your case, `/subdirectory/index.php?/Main_Page`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this does get the roll over to /index.php/Main_Page but the site doesn't load and the error is

    failed (20: Not a directory)

Comment: I added this line above the one posted in the OP then modified the try_files

    location /alv/ {
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri /alv/index.php?query_string;
    }

Comment: yes, using above code will forward all the requests to index.php, in your case, `/subdirectory/index.php/Main_Page` which is path of a folder but it should be `/subdirectory/index.php?/Main_Page`. so instead you could use `rewrite`.